# cannot login to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I am basically stuck to the login screen of phpmyadmin. If I enter the username and password and click on `Go`, the page just refreshes.

I have restarted the mysql server on ubuntu to no effect

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Any help?

Edit: I can login using `mysql` command from the terminal.

Comment: do you have lampp or they are installed separately ?

Comment: @InfMin, did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Please clear cached your browser.
[clear change on firefox](http://akbarbin.blogspot.com/2011/06/phpmyadmin-error-cannot-start-session.html?q=phpmyadmin)

Comment: I have done that. It is not a cache issue. I get the same problem on different browsers and computers.

Answer (score 0):

If the phpmyadmin keep kicking back when login

ssh to the remote server with sudoer privilege.
type mysql -u username(normally root) -p

In mysql command prompt type

set password for ‘username’@’localhost’ =password(‘yourpassword’);
flush privileges;